# Is there a way to repeat 'A number in the middle of a loop' multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, math

Let's say this is a loop I am aiming for, Starting with 10 and ending at 6.

```
for i in range(10,6,-1):
        print(i)
```

But I want to print 8 multiple times.

- The output expected is 10, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6

so if the loop is going on downhill, Is there a way to stop at a certain point and repeat just the value again and again for N number of times?

Comment: Consider using a second nested loop. Alternatively, be aware that you can do fancy operation in python like `'repeated'*10` or `[42]*10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple one with hard-cording:

```
for i in range(10,5,-1):
        if i == 8:
            for _ in range(3):
                print(i)
        else:
            print(i)
```

Output:

```
10
9
8
8
8
7
6
```

Answer (score 0):

For a solution with a single loop body,

```
for i in range(10, 5 - 2, -1):
    j= i + min(2, max(0, 8 - i))
    print(j)
```

---

You can replace `8` by another number to be repeated and `2` by another repetition count.

Comment: :D. Code golf! I only hope the maintainer of the code is not some violent psychopath etc. But super cool!

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of doing the same with a `while` block -

```py
loop_range = range(10, 6, -1)
it = iter(loop_range)
while True:
    try:
        item = next(it)
        if item == 8:
            print(*[item]*3, sep='\n')
        print(item)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

The same construct can be made more terse and more readable using a generator expression -

```py
custom_sequence = ((_,)*3 if _ == 8 else (_,) for _ in range(10, 6, -1))
for i in custom_sequence:
    print(*i, sep='\n')
```